# Reversing and vtable swapping in dxgi.dll

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

I want to render by DXGI and need to get the SwapChain.

I want to swap the vtable from DXGI.
I don't want anyone to say that I can render in other method or just create the swap chain, but I know
and I cannot do with other method. That's the task I have problem with.

I reversed the DXGI.dll with IDA Pro and have these sigs:

For Windows 10:

- Signature: `48 C7 40 B8 FE FF FF FF 48 89 58 18`
- Dereference: `sig + *(signed int*)(sig + 0x25) + 0x29;`

For Windows 11:

- Signature: `48 83 EC 50 49 8B D8 48 8B F9 4D 8B C1 48 8B D3 E8 ? ? ? ? 90`
- Dereference: `sig + *(signed int*)(sig + 0x19) + 0x1D;`

I do not know how to swap the vtable and hook the Present function or get the Swap Chain.
I want to render my overlay by doing this.

Also if you've scanned the dxgi.dll using IDA with these sigs and dereferneced it
please send me a screenshots as I want to know exactly how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

I except somebody to help me with swapping the vtable or hooking the Present from it, I don't know exactly.
I want to render the overlay by doing it.